# I've created a fade in fade out jquery content box, i want it to stop on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

In this code i am making a box with data which are displaying one after another two li 
box but i want it to stop when mouseenter over it and to countinue when mouse leave.

#### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/mxbeE)

### CSS :

```
ul.bxslider li{
width:77%;
margin: 50px 0 0 80px;
height:150px;
display:none;
text-align:left;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight:normal;
font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
}
```

### HTML Code :

```
 <ul class="bxslider">
      <li class="fader">1)&nbsp;&nbsp;Testimonial ticker goest here,
               showing all testimonials one by one.
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Testimonial ticker goest here, showing
               all testimonials one by one.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Testimonial ticker
               goest here, showing all testimonials one by one
     </li>
     <li class="fader">2)&nbsp;&nbsp;Testimonial ticker goest here,
            showing all testimonials one by one<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Testimonial ticker goest here, showing
            all testimonials one by one<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Testimonial ticker goest here, showing
            all testimonials one by one
    </li>

    </ul>
```

### JavaScript Code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(fadeLoop) {

        var fad = $('.fader');
        var counter = 0;
        var divs = $('.fader').hide(); // Selecting fader divs instead of each by name.
        var dur = 500;

        fad.children().filter('.fader').each(function(fad) {

            function animator(currentItem) {

                animator(fad.children(":first"));

                fad.mouseenter(function(){
                    $(".fader").stop(); 
                });
                fad.mouseleave(function(){
                    animator(fad.children(":first"));
                });
            };

        });

        function showDiv() {
            divs.fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
                .filter(function(index) {
                    return index == counter % divs.length;
                }) // figure out correct div to show
                .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
                .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
            counter++;
        }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div

        showDiv(); // show first div    

        return setInterval(function() {  // return interval so we can stop the loop
            showDiv(); // show next div
        }, 2 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds    
   });

// JavaScript Document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two variables that contain all of the faders.  I assume you wanted one for the faders, and one for the `ul`.

```
var fad = $('.bxslider');
var divs = $('.fader').hide();
var dur = 500;
```

We can create a variable to hold the next element, and a variable that indicates whether the animation should stop, or not.

```
var stop = false;
var next = $();
```

We can check for a mouse being over the entire list which is more reliable.

```
fad.mouseenter(function(){
    stop = true;
});
fad.mouseleave(function(){
    stop = false;
});
```

Our new-and-improved `showDiv` function checks if we need to stop before doing anything.  It's also restructured to make sure that we'll have something visible for when we tell it to stop animating.

```
function showDiv() {
    if (stop) return;
    if (next.length) {
        next.fadeOut(dur);
    }
    next = next.next();
    if (next.length === 0) 
        next = divs.first();
    next.delay(dur).fadeIn(dur);      
};
```

The the usual timer.  We can rewrite it to just pass the function.

```
showDiv();    
setInterval(showDiv, 2 * 1000);
```

### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/qneKD)

Comment: Thanks you so much sir .. i've implemented your suggested code and its working absolutely fine ..